# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while converting nvarchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `usda_losses_temp` which has a `nvarchar(50)` type column named `end_date` which are date values in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I am trying to put this data in a new column called `end` using the following query:

```
update usda_losses_temp 
set end = cast((substring(hazard_end_date, 1, 4) + '-'+ substring(hazard_end_date, 6, 2) + '-'+ substring(hazard_end_date, 9, 2)) as date)
```

However, I am getting the error that:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Example query:

```
update usda_losses_temp 
set end_date = cast((substring('2020-09-31', 1, 4) + '-'+ substring('2020-09-31', 6, 2) + '-'+ substring('2020-09-31', 9, 2)) as date)
```

I also tried

```sql
update usda_losses_temp 
set end = FORMAT((substring(hazard_end_date, 1, 4) + '-'+ substring(hazard_end_date, 6, 2) + '-'+ substring(hazard_end_date, 9, 2)),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

but it gave me an error saying:

> Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.

I am not able to make it work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. Though you *need* to fix your design. There are 6 date and time data types to choose from, why are you not using them?

Comment: You can use any value for `hazard_end_date` to get the error. I updated the query above.

Comment: I am working on an old db, so not my choice to select data type. Sorry :(

Comment: It's pretty hard to turn `2020-09-31` into a date, since September only has 30 days. This is yet another reason you (or they) should have never made the illogical decision to store dates in a string column in the first place.

Comment: *"so not my choice to select data type"* It wasn't your choice when it was created, but it your choice to not fix it.

Comment: `You can use any value for hazard_end_date to get the error` - no, this is not true. It will work fine for September 30th, but not for September 31st because that is fake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample date, `'2020-09-31'`, can't be converted to a date, regardless of what kind of formatting or substrings you apply to it. **September only has 30 days.**

Thus revealing the underlying problem: These never should have been stored as strings in the first place.

To find the offending rows:

```
SELECT * FROM usda_losses_temp WHERE ISDATE(hazard_end_date) = 0;
```

Once you've fixed your bad data, you should use the simple `CONVERT, col, 120)` syntax Dale suggested, instead of all this messy substring goop.

And add a check constraint (`CHECK (ISDATE(hazard_end_date)) = 1`) until you or they can fix the table. Because that is the real problem here.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) with the correct (120) format?

```
update usda_losses_temp set [end] =  convert(date, hazard_end_date, 120);
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4462d8a919653f87e0af3e9065a520c3)

If thats not working then you have some invalid dates for the format provided within your data.

Comment: it gives the same error to me

Comment: @vipin8169 you must have some dates in another format then, because that works for the format provided.

Comment: got it. I tried this earlier but it did not work. the problem as pointed above is that the date is wrong, as september cant have 31 days

Answer (score -1):

Try using convert() instead of cast():

```
update usda_losses_temp 
set end_date = CONVERT(datetime,(substring('2015-09-29', 1, 4) + '-'+ substring('2020-09-29', 6, 2) + '-'+ substring('2020-09-29', 9, 2)+'T23:59:59.000'), 126)
```

Also '2020-09-31' throws me an out-of-range converting exception from varchar. Datetime does implicitly convert to date for date fields.